# Javascript: Calculating time difference returns none issue

Tags: javascript, function, return, trim, floor

I am trying to calculate the time difference between the start and the end with the format hr/min/sec. My issue with my function below is that my `console.log` does not return any value. Hope to get some assistance with that.

```
            var mf_start   = "10:30:30";
            var mf_end     = "11:10:10";

            function time_interval(mf_start,mf_end)
            {
                $s = mf_start;
                $e = mf_end;
                if ($s < $e)
                {
                    $a = $e - $s;
                }
                else
                {
                    $e = '+1 day',$e;
                    $a = $e - $s;
                }
                
                $h = Math.floor($a/3600);
                $m = Math.floor(($a%3600)/60);
                $s = $a%60;
                
                var str = ($h?$h+' hour ':'')+($m?$m+' minute ':'')+($s?$s + ' second ':'');
                return str.trim();
            }
            
            var c = time_interval(mf_start,mf_end);
            console.log(c);
```

Screenshot of the Console, it's blank: (main issue)

[image: 1]

What I tried:

I am getting an unexpected string error on my trim if I do the code like

```
return trim(($h?$h.' hour ':'').($m?$m.' minute ':'').($s?$s.' second ':''));
```

so I separated it with a variable first then returned with the trim.

Expected Output (based on values given):

```
39 minute 40 second
```

Comment: `"11:10:10" - "10:30:30"`   === `NaN` you can't subtract strings ... `return trim(...)` - trim is not a function, unless you create it

Comment: you'll need a function to convert `"hh:mm:ss"` to seconds ... `const stringToSeconds=s => s.split(':').map(Number).reduce((a,b)=>a*60+b);` will do it

Comment: Also, stop using global variables unless absolutely necessary ... i.e. `$s`, `$e`, `$a`, `$h`, `$m` - and name those variables better if you want readable code

Answer (score 1):

Please change code from

```
$s = mf_start;
$e = mf_end;
```

to

```
$s = mf_start.split(":");
$s = Number($s[0])*3600 + Number($s[1])*60 + Number($s[2]);
$e = mf_end.split(":");
$e = Number($e[0])*3600 + Number($e[1])*60 + Number($e[2]);
```